# Design Patterns - Choosing between builder and abstract factory

Tags: design-patterns, factory, abstract, builder

reading GoF, seems to me like the only difference between the abstract factory and the builder is that the latter has one extra layer of abstraction to hide implementation from the client. But there should be something more, right? The builder should be more useful if we're dealing with graphs, but why!?

I'm just getting into this stuff, so if someone could please give me some examples of a "builder vs abstract factory" situation it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Example of a Builder: java.lang.StringBuilder. Example of an abstract factory: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory#newInstance(). The two patterns don't solve the same problem. a Builder helps creating a complex, usually immutable, object, from various parts. An abstract factory allows creating an instance of an appropriate subclass of an abstract base class based on configuration parameters.

Comment: Just found this main difference on the interweb: 
    Abstract Factory: Focus on defining many different types of *factories* to build many *products*, and it is not a one builder for just one product---
    Builder: Focus on building a one complex but one single *product*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of a `Builder` as a kind of constructor that instead of giving all the input parameters at the same time to the constructor, you can delay giving all the parameters until later.  This is very useful for building up an object over time or passing a Builder instance around to other objects or methods so they can add their parameters etc.  Once all the parameters are added calling the builder's `build()` method will create exactly one instance of the built object.  Calling `build()` again will either create another identical instance or throw an error depending on the builder implementation.

In Java, a `StringBuilder` is a common Builder example. StringBuilders a let you append/insert/delete characters or other Strings over time.  Then when you are done building the String, calling `StringBuilder.toString()` will create just one new String object.  This is much more efficient than concatenating many Stings together, where each Java String concatenation will create a new String instance.

The `AbstractFactory` pattern is used to create different `Factory` classes where each factory instance can create several different types of objects. An example AbstractFactory in Java is the JDBC classes.  The JDBC `DriverManager` class is an abstract factory that creates different `Connection` instances that are connections to a database.   Which `Connection` instance is returned depends on which database you are using and what drivers you have registered.  The `Connection` class is a `Factory` which lets you create different kinds of `Statement` objects depending on what the parameter values you give it.

```
Statement statement = myConnection.createStatement(sqlString);

Statement otherStatement = myConnection.createStatement(differentSqlString);
```